# Writing a shell script in Ubuntu to process several layers as a single animated GIF file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell-script, 32bit

I am an Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 32-bit user and I would like to automate the process of opening several PNG images as layers then saving these layers as a single animated GIF file in the GUI of GIMP. My intention is to write a BASH script but I have no idea on how to do that. I would be indebted if someone can provide help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is the GIMP part really necessary? This is exactly what ImageMagick is designed for -- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/

Comment: *If* you want to do this with gimp, the best way to do it is probably with [script-fu](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/ca/gimp-concepts-script-fu.html), which uses scheme, perl, python, or tcl.

Comment: @ToxicFrog Apologies for my late comment but GIMP is not compulsory. What do you suggest that I do?

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks, but I am not familiar with script-fu but I would take a look at that.

Comment: @Vesnog the same thing as the answer slm gave you :) ImageMagick is seriously amazing for command-line image processing.

Comment: @ToxicFrog Yeah that program is a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ImageMagick you can convert a stack of PNG files into an animated GIF quite easily.

```
$ convert -delay 60 -loop 0 *.png sample.gif
```

I've used this technique to create several animated GIFs on this very site, for example, [What is difference between w and W in escape mode of vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106425/what-is-difference-between-w-and-w-in-escape-mode-of-vim/).

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, it seems easier than GIMP command line mode, I will give it a try.